# Debugging Heroku using logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, postgresql, heroku, npm

React frontend with rails backend. Deploying with NPM. Deployed successfully but failing to fetch with this error--

```
heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/users"
```

There's no information in the logs about what crashed it ends with:

```
2020-06-19T01:21:42.298326+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-06-19T01:21:42.342497+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I get this warning when pushing to heroku

```
remote:        Detecting rails configuration failed
remote:        set HEROKU_DEBUG_RAILS_RUNNER=1 to debug
```

I've been googling this all day and can not find a solution. What I can gather is that it just isn't connecting to the postgres db. How do I debug this?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually ssh into the heroku using the heroku-cli instance to try to start rails server on your own.
or look into the log folder.

```sh
heroku ps:exec -a your-app-name
```